# SAP user change

Tags: web-services, struct, vbscript, sap-basis, bapi

I am using VB Script to Access SAP web Services, the sap web service has a method called user change, there are 3 mandatory parameters username, password and passwordX.

Here username is string so I can assign value without any problem, password is a type of Bapipwd. Bapipwd is a structure and it has a member called Bapipwd. To access that from VB script I have to use

```
Bapipwd.Bapipwd = "Password".
```

But when I try to put the statement Bapipwd.Bapipwd = "password" it shows an error message that "Bapipwd doesnt have member called Bapipwd".

The passwordX also a structure in SAP with the name of Bapipwdx and it has a member "Bapipwd"

If I user Bapipwdx.Bapipwd="X" it is working fine. Because both the structure and it's member name is different. But Bapipwd.Bapipwd is not working and it gives "Bapipwd doestn't have member Bapipwd"

I suspect this is due to both the structure and its member has the same name. Kindly help me to access the structure.